# printing the short name of a class

Tags: python

Is there a way to print the short name of a class without the qualifiers? For instance

```
c = numbers.Number
print(c??)  # should print Number
c = re.Pattern 
print(c??)  # should print Pattern
```

I know I can use regex to filter out the unwanted text but I am trying to do this for all classes. So what should I put in place of `??`?

Answer (score 7):

```py
print(Number.__name__)
# for object
print(Number().__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: What if it is a class that cannot be instantiated or one that takes in non zero number of args in its init? Ex: `c = re.Pattern print(c().__class__.__name__)   # TypeError: cannot create 're.Pattern' instances`

Comment: Why do you want create re.Pattern instance to get the name ?

Comment: Just try re.Pattern.__name__